# How to get a row value from database table to use it in JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I want to retrieve a row value from database.
Since we need serverside to access database we have to use PHP to retrive the value but I am not sure how to use this php in a .js file.

This is what I am trying but it does not work.
The reason is simple.. we can not write PHP inside a javascript file.

file.js:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pwd, $db_name);
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Holders WHERE username='$username'";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
$address = $row['address'];
?>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var addressFrmPHP = "<?= $address; ?>";
    var url = "https://api.examlesite.io/api?module=account&action=bal&add=000000000&address="+addressFrmPHP+"&tag=latest&apikey=APIKEY";
});
```

How can I assign the php `$address` variable to javascript `addressFrmPHP` variable?

Comment: you cannot use php inside `js` file

Comment: So what's the solution? I mentioned in my question what you've mentioned @vel is there any way to get a database table row value and use it in jS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You have to create two files as shown below

> getdata.php

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pwd, $db_name);
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Holders WHERE username='$username'";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
$address = $row['address'];
echo $address;
?>
```

> file.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    /* AJAX for get data from php page */

    $.post('getdata.php', function(address) {

        var addressFrmPHP = address;
    });

    var url = "https://api.examlesite.io/api?module=account&action=bal&add=000000000&address="+addressFrmPHP+"&tag=latest&apikey=APIKEY";
});
```

Comment: +1 - Ajax ($.post) is probably what OP was looking for. OP: I would recommend adding some errorhandling (what happens if `$_SESSION['username']` is not set? could that potentially happen?)

Answer (score 1):

you have to do like this

**test.php**

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pwd, $db_name);
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Holders WHERE username='$username'";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
$address = $row['address'];

echo '<script> var address= '.$address.';</scrpit>';
?>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/file.js'></script>
```

**file.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var addressFrmPHP = address;
    var url = "https://api.examlesite.io/api?module=account&action=bal&add=000000000&address="+addressFrmPHP+"&tag=latest&apikey=APIKEY";
});
```

Comment: so how to include test.php in file.js or file.js in test.php ? then only we can use this right?

Answer (score 1):

**Create One file Getdata.php and write the below code:**

```
<?php 
    $con = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pwd, $db_name);
    $username = 'nirav4491';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Holders WHERE username='$username'";
    $data = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
    $address = $row['address'];

?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var addressFrmPHP = '<?php echo $address; ?>';
            var url = "https://api.examlesite.io/api?module=account&action=bal&add=000000000&address="+addressFrmPHP+"&tag=latest&apikey=APIKEY";
            alert(url);
        });

    </script>
</head>
</html>
```